# setting default date format in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried a couple of different solutions to try and set the default format in rails so that when a date is displayed in a form field like...

```
<%=f.text_field :start_date %>
```

it should display as mm/dd/yyyy.  Instead I'm getting dates such as 2014-10-28 00:00:00.000000

What I have tried so far is adding the following to my en.yml file

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%m/%d/%Y"
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
```

I also added this to my initializers/date_formats.rb file

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => '%m-%d-%Y')
Time::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(:default => "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M")
```

So, any idea why none of these are working?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use localization you have to express that in your view with the `l` helper method, like:

```
 <%= f.text_field :start_date, :value => l(@job.start_date.to_date) %>
```

Only now will Rails try to format the value with your localization settings. It is using the formatting as defined for `Time`, since `:start_date` probably is of type `DateTime`.

The format definitions in `config/locales/en.yml` should be sufficient.

Comment: That code doesn't work but it did head me in the right direction.  Thanks!  What worked for me was, <%= f.text_field :start_date, :value => l(@job.start_date.to_date)%>

Comment: Great! I updated the answer to include your correction.